# Unable to apt update - asking for apt-transport-hhtps

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt, gnome

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS & Gnome 3.36.8.

When running the following command:
`sudo apt update`

I get this error:

```
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/hhtps could not be found.

N: Is the package apt-transport-hhtps installed?
```

While apt-transport-https is a real package, ...-hhtps isn't.

Can anyone tell me why this has happened, and how I might go about fixing it?

`/usr/lib/apt/methods/https` does exist so assume for whatever reason it's pointing to the wrong place when I try to update it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s a typo in one of your repository references;

```
grep -r hhtps /etc/apt/sources.list*
```

should tell you where. Fix that, and you’ll be able to update again.